# Detect changes in user locale setting (Control Panel -> Clock,Language and Region) in child dialog box

Tags: winapi, locale, regional-settings, control-panel

I have dialog box made in resource editor that behaves as a child control of the main window.

In normal mode, when behaving as a popup, dialog can receive [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) message that notifies dialog box about user changing locale settings, but as a child it does not seem to receive this message -> after setting up a breakpoint at relevant code, the debugger never reaches those lines.

Is there a way to detect in child dialog box when user changes locale in Control Panel?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the locale changes?

Comment: `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` is sent to top-level windows only. So if your child window needs to know about it, have your top-level window forward it on.

Comment: @andlabs: *What are you trying to do with the locale changes?* I am implementing locale aware decimal edit control ( xxxxx@yyyy, where xxxxx and yyyy are numbers and @ is decimal separator ). I need proper decimal number in the edit control because I enter its value into database.  If not formatted per user locale, the decimal part gets cut off. See the 3rd answer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/728310/Locale-aware-edit-control-subclassing-for-decimal?arn=0) question for specific details.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: All is well now. If you post your comment as an answer I will officially accept and upvote it. You have deserved it! Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_SETTINGCHANGE` is sent to top-level windows only. So if your child window needs to know about it, have your top-level window forward it on (i.e. with `SendMessage(hwndChild, uMsg, wParam, lParam);` or similar).